# How to add a C program between libc and syscall in Android?

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, glibc, libc

I'm developing a project in android.Which will intercept all of the I/O request(read/write) in an application.Now I decide to achieve it in libc's read/write function.But I found that the read/write function is written by assembly language.

> bionic/libc/arch-arm/syscalls/read.S

Our project is complex which means that we can't make it by change assembly language code.I'm considering about rename the assembly read syscall to __read,then write a C function read() to replace the assembly read()  function,all of other call of the read() will call the C read() instead of assembly read().The C read() simply call the assembly __read function.So that I could do something before the read function called.But I don't know how to do it. Kindly review and give feedback for instructions to be used or if you have some other ideas about how to intercept the I/O in an app is fine,too.I'm using Android 6.0.1 on Nexus 6.Or Android 8 on Pixel2 is fine too.

Comment: You can't do that as an app developer, because you don't control the copy of libc in use, because your process is only a fork of a process into which the system's libc was already loaded. Back in the Android 1.3 days on a single core I managed to get an app to live patch its own running copy, not sure that would work today.  Likely you should find a different way to achieve whatever your *actual* goal is.

Comment: But if you are a system developer building AOSP from source and not trying to make an app that runs on a stock build of Android, sure, you can modify libc.  Just realize that read() and write() are not the only applicable calls.  Mapping of files directly into memory could complicate your unstated goals quite a bit...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.I have solved this problem.Firstly change the read.S to __read.S and replace the read by __read in read.S. Then write a read.cpp in bionic/libc/bionic,the content is:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/read.h>
#include "private/libc_logging.h"

extern "C" ssize_t __read(int, void *, size_t);

ssize_t read(int a, void * b, size_t c){
    /* 测试时打印log用
    const char * tag = "DebugRead"; 
    const char * format = "%s"; 
    const char * msg = "Cpp read() called";
    __libc_format_log(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, tag, format, msg);
    */

    return __read(a,b,c);
}
```

the write a read.h in bionic/libc/include/sys.the code is:

```
#ifndef _SYS_READ_H_
#define _SYS_READ_H_

#include <linux/unistd.h>

__BEGIN_DECLS

extern ssize_t __read(int, void *, size_t);

__END_DECLS

#endif /* _SYS_READ_H_ */
```

finally add a bionic/read.cpp \ in bionic/libc/Android.mk is OK.